# Oracle SQL - select all maximum column values from query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

let's say this is my table:

```
 Name    |  Surname      | Serial no.  | Price
-----------------------------------------------
 John    |  Smith        | A12444dW33  | 1,234 
 Paul    |  Harrison     | D2344fGGfd  | 2,5
 Richard |  Morris       | We945kfGGE  | 3
 George  |  Washington   | ssf4gt66hJ  | 7,39494
```

How do I get actual **LONGEST** values for each column in **ONE** row, based on length ?

I need something that will be valid for every datatype - **NUMBER, VARCHAR,DATE** etc.

Output for example table should be (Serial no. are all same length, so that is not important here...):

```
 Name    |  Surname      | Serial no.  | Price
-----------------------------------------------
 Richard |  Washington   | A12444dW33  | 7,39494
```

All questions I found are focused on use with one column only, but I need solution for all columns.

Comment: DATE values all have the same length...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`keep`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm):

```
select max(name) keep (dense_rank first order by length(name) desc),
       max(Surname) keep (dense_rank first order by length(Surname) desc),
       max(serial) keep (dense_rank first order by length(serial) desc),
       max(price) keep (dense_rank first order by length(price) desc)
from t;
```

Comment: ,thanks, I will try ASAP. I'm only afraid of performance issues, my actual queries are slow to process, this will probably make them even slower.

Comment: @Lucy82 . . . I have found that `keep` is more efficient than other alternatives when I've kept track of the performance.

Comment: amazing, this thing is super fast. But what about possible white spaces in VARCHAR, should I use TRIM over values just in case ?

Comment: @Lucy82 . . . If you want to remove spaces, then use `trim()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `MAX( column ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK [FIRST|LAST] ORDER BY ... )`:

```sql
SELECT MAX( Name      ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY LENGTH( Name      ) DESC ) AS Name,
       MAX( Surname   ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY LENGTH( Surname   ) DESC ) AS Surname,
       MAX( Serial_no ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY LENGTH( Serial_no ) DESC ) AS serial_no,
       MAX( Price     ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY LENGTH( Price     ) DESC ) AS Price
FROM   your_table;
```

outputs:

> ```
> NAME    | SURNAME    | SERIAL_NO  |   PRICE
> :------ | :--------- | :--------- | ------:
> Richard | Washington | ssf4gt66hJ | 7.39494
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bd4f2f0f7aafd0a31415c53ed6108260)*